# NSWindow on second NSScreen OSX 10.13.4 or higher

Tags: xcode, nswindow

## NSWindow not placed on right frame in second screen.

With new OSX version I have the problem that I can set Frame but `NSWindow` will not set on correct screen. Only if I use `setFrame` animated works.

But it looks strange and cost performance. Somebody know what can help...

I try many things... but only animation bring window to the right `NSScreen`.

```
[fullScreenWindowPlaylist setFrame: screen.frame display:YES]; // not work

[fullScreenWindowPlaylist setFrame: screen.frame display:YES animate:YES]; // works
```

Greetings

Comment: First, what if you use the `...animate:` method with `NO`? If that doesn't help, does the animation behavior work well enough if you override `-animationResizeTime:` to return 0?

Comment: If is use animate: NO it don't work that is the strange thing. i Made this..

[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
            context.duration = 0.00000000000000001f;
            [[fullScreenWindowPlaylist animator] setFrame:mainDisplayRect display:YES];
        } completionHandler:^{
             [fullScreenWindowPlaylist setIsVisible:YES];
        }]

if i use duration 0.0f it dont work... it looks like a strange bug of new OSX

Comment: The big question is why set frame on a second screen dont work with new OSX?